# How to write a SQL query implementing Excel SUMIFS function

Tags: sql, excel, sumifs

I have a table like this:

```
Date        Sales   Department Store
02/01/2012   4.09    Toys       A
03/01/2012   5.90    Toys       A
02/01/2012   6.64    Toys       B
03/01/2012   4.71    Toys       B
02/01/2012   16.72   Toys       C
03/01/2012   1.37    Toys       C
02/01/2012   13.22   Movies     A
03/01/2012   18.06   Movies     A
02/01/2012   5.97    Movies     B
03/01/2012   16.71   Movies     B
02/01/2012   15.38   Movies     C
03/01/2012   19.75   Movies     C
```

And want a table like this, where only Store A and B are considered:

```
Date        Toys    Movies
02/01/2012   10.73   19.19 
03/01/2012   10.61   34.77
```

Here the SUMIFS function we would use in EXCEL:

```
=SUMIFS(Value;Date;$H4;Department;I$3;Store;"<>C")
```

What can we write in SQL?

Take into consideration this is a short exaple, the database table has over 30 Departments and more many Dates. I was using the script

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date,
ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Department = 'Toys'  AND Store = 'A' THEN Sales END),0) +
ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Department = 'Toys'  AND Store = 'B' THEN Sales END),0) [Toys],
ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Department = 'Movies'  AND Store = 'A' THEN Sales END),0) +
ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Department = 'Movies'  AND Store = 'B' THEN Sales END),0) [Movies]
FROM Table$
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date
```

... but it is not efficient. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is ok, but it can be improved a bit:

```
SELEC Date,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Department = 'Toys' THEN Sales else 0 END) as [Toys],
      MAX(CASE WHEN Department = 'Movies' THEN Sales else 0 END) as [Movies]
FROM Table$
WHERE store in ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date;
```

This removes the `distinct`, which is unnecessary with a `group by`.  It moves the condition on `store` to the `where` clause, because it applies to all the rows.  And, it removes the `ISNULL()` by including `else 0` in the `case` statement -- so stores with no sales in the department will return a `0` instead of `NULL`.