# Translating SUMIF to TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code and the following query which is written in SQL Server Management Studio 2012;

```
WITH cteUniqueClients AS 
(
    SELECT  
        CASE
           WHEN ServiceActualEndDate IS NULL
                AND LAG(ClientID,1) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID, ServiceProvider ORDER BY ServiceActualEndDate DESC, StartDateFormatted DESC) = ClientID
              THEN 0
           WHEN ServiceActualEndDate IS NOT NULL
              THEN 0
           ELSE 1
        END AS UniqueClient,
        CASE 
           WHEN LAG(ActualHoursPerWeek,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID, ServiceProvider ORDER BY StartDateFormatted DESC) = ActualHoursPerWeek
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
        END AS UniqueService,
        ClientID, ClientName,
        ActualHoursPerWeek,
        ServicePlannedStartDate, ServiceActualStartDate
    FROM 
        dbo.tTable1
    WHERE
        (ServiceActualStartDate <= '2016-08-09' OR ServicePlannedStartDate <= '2016-08-09')
        AND ServiceActualEndDate IS NULL
        AND (ServicePlannedEndDate > '2016-08-09' OR ServicePlannedEndDate IS NULL)
        AND ClientDeathDate IS NULL         
)
SELECT 
    COUNT(ClientID) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY ClientID) AS RecordCount,
    cteUniqueClients.*
FROM 
    cteUniqueClients
WHERE 
    UniqueService = 1
ORDER BY 
    ClientID ASC
```

And the following Excel formula:

```
=SUMIF(G2:G961,G2,I2:I961)
```

Where column G would be `ClientID` and Column I would be `ActualHoursPerWeek`.

Is there any way to marry these two up whilst keeping all of the report columns?

Below is an image of the example Excel output which would be desired;

[image: Updated Excel Output]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `SUMIF`? It looks like adding up `ActualHoursPerWeek` for the `ClientID` from that row and all lower rows (higher rows excluded). So if `ClientID` is the same in rows 1-3, row one would get the sum of 1-3, row 2 would get the sum of 2-3 and row 3 would get itself. (Assuming that the formula was created in one cell and copied down.)

Comment: @SMM That is exactly how the excel file has the results yes. I can then sort the data by ClientID and AcutalHoursPerWeek and use the unique client column to and show only the unique clients but also they're total hours.

Sorry if that is a bit wordy

Comment: So I would then expect the original sheet to have a very specific sort order to make sure the sums only include lower rows...what is that sort order? Are those columns included in the table? It might help to see the source Excel you used to create the desired output image. Also, maybe also the table schema.

Comment: @SMM Not an extremely specific sort order only by ascending ClientID. The above sql query was used to create the excel output, I only calculated the HoursPerClient column.

Comment: Can we assume then that in the sample that `Hours Per Client` is what we are trying to calculate and that by reverse-engineering that the `ActualHoursPerWeek` for James would be 1.19, 1.75, 2.31, 3.5, and 7 to get that output since your spreadsheet does not seem to go to column I to know its values? If that 7 were to come first instead of last then your new values for James would become 15.75, 8.75, 7.56, 5.81, and 3.5...I think if you want to make this reliable you need an additional sort column like date or something...

Comment: @SMM absolutely correct with your reverse-engineering assumption. I'll update the example pic to include column I ('ActualHoursPerWeek') and this may give you a better idea. Though now looking at it that column name is no longer valid so I'll alter it to ActualHoursPerService.

Comment: there is already an answer [How to write a SQL query implementing Excel SUMIFS function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294973/how-to-write-a-sql-query-implementing-excel-sumifs-function)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry...busy day :-) As someone posted above I believe there are ways to do this. However I think the key here is paying attention to you sort orders. I have written the following code that will get you what you need with caveats. I included my test table.

```
declare @tbl table (
Ident                   int identity (1,1),
RecordCount             int,
UniqueClient            int,
ClientID                int,
ClientName              varchar(20),
ActualHoursPerService   float
);

insert into @tbl values
(1,1,1,'Pam',18.75),
(1,1,2,'Collin',8.75),
(1,1,3,'William',19.83),
(1,1,4,'Andy',10),
(5,0,5,'James',1.19),
(5,0,5,'James',1.75),
(5,0,5,'James',2.31),
(5,0,5,'James',3.5),
(5,0,5,'James',7),
(1,1,6,'Ford',12)

select * from @tbl order by ClientID;

select  sum(t.ActualHoursPerService) over (partition by t.ClientID order by t.Ident desc rows unbounded preceding) HoursPerClient
        ,*
from    @tbl t
order   by t.ClientID, t.Ident;
```

You will notice that I created an `Ident` column in my source table (which would be your CTE. Otherwise the rows for James can be out of order and then you will have different running totals with each row. You should probably pick something like `ServiceActualEndDate` as your order by in the partition statement and use that in your final ordering as well.

For reference, here is a list of ways to do running totals which I made into a reverse running total to match what you were looking to do: [link](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/grouped-running-totals)

Hope this is enough to get you there!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer I'll try this out later today and get back to you with the results.