# Sumifs SQL table Match Row Value

Tags: mysql, sum

What I'm trying to do is create a SUM case when statement, just like a sumifs in Excel.  Which I'll pull into R to do further analysis but figured it'd be quicker to run this query once in MySQL and pull into R.

So in Excel it works with `=SUMIFS(I:I,H:H,"Shipping",G:G,G7,F:F, F7)`(this formula being in the "total_cost" column.

Where column H is the `process`, G is the `order_no`, and F is the `parent_name`

The part I'm not sure about is how to match the row value G7 & F7 among the entire range (or even if that's efficient considering this small db has a few million rows * 45 columns) in this example, would fill in the total_cost column for that cell.

So below I'm trying to get the total cost of the orders per order number per parent.  All orders have processes in them (compiling, packing, shipping) with shipping being the end.  So in the "total_cost" column, it will sum all the costs for the current row's `order_no` and `parent_name` when the process = Shipping.

I get a "invalid use of group function" with the below.  I tried following [This SUMIFS in SQL Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294973/how-to-write-a-sql-query-implementing-excel-sumifs-function) but can't seem to fit the `GROUP BY` in to work.

```
    UPDATE m.data
    set total_cost = 
    IF(process = 'Shipping',
                  SUM(case when order_no = order_no
                      AND parent_name = parent_name
                            THEN sum(process_cost) else 0 END), "")
```

Or let me know if you have a better way of course.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a update with inner join on sum group by order_no

```
update data
inner join (
  select order_no , sum(process_cost) as my_sum
  from data
  group by order_no
  ) t on t.order_no = data.order_no and data.process=  'Shipping'
set total_cost  = my_sum
```

Comment: Still getting the same error.  But from other posts I've read, it seems I need a "HAVING" clause, although not sure where to put it at the moment.

Comment: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.